# How to use debugger in express for async functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I'm using express and I have the following end-point:

```
router.get('/', async (_req, res) => {
  const customers = await Customer.find().sort({ name: 1 });

  res.status(200).json(customers);
});
```

I would like to set a debugger here:

```
router.get('/', async (_req, res) => {
  debugger // <--- Adding this here
  const customers = await Customer.find().sort({ name: 1 });

  res.status(200).json(customers);
});
```

Now I run my app like so:

```
node inspect app.js
```

Once in the debugger, I try to use the `repl` and/or use the inspect console in Chrome... but when I try to interact with my `Customer` model with the `await` keyword, I get:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

I would like to play with this query in real-time while debugging the current state of the app. Is there a way to achieve this in node/js?

Comment: what node version?

Comment: @Sergeon v14.15.0

Comment: Without debuger mode, your code don’t have ant error?

Comment: No, there's no errors in the code. I'm trying to understand how I can interact with the ORM during runtime using a debugger.

Comment: if you use vscode you can debug your code easier